# Getting Error During dotnet build in VSTS CI/CD error : rzc generate exited with code 1

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am getting an error while using CI/CD to build dotnet mvc application.

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.402\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(52,5):
>   warning MSB3052: The parameter to the compiler is invalid,
>   '/define:$(BUILDCONFIGURATION)' will be ignored. [D:\a\1\s\x.csproj]
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.1.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(121,5):
>   error : rzc generate exited with code 1. [D:\a\1\s\x.csproj] error :
>   rzc generate exited with code 1.

While it working in my local machine.

Answer (score 28):

I was banging my head against this for a while after using our standard build template to build a new project based on the dotnet angular spa template.

What this comes down to is the build target for razor pages **requiring** an explicit build configuration to be provided, thus any project containing razor pages fails without one.

Confusingly, a dotnet build task for a project with no razor pages will flag it as a warning and continue (notably without raising a warning in the Azure Devops UI). This lead me to the erroneous assumption that the missing parameter was a red herring.

**Solution**

Go into the variables tab of the pipeline settings and add a new pipeline variable named `BuildConfiguration` with value either `Debug` or `Release` (depending on what you're building).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, Thanks @Taylor

Comment: this helps solve my problem also. thank you so much :)

Comment: That solved for me also, thanks!

Comment: Great! solved my problem as well :)