# Azure DevOps build "rzc generate exited with code 1"

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops

The last container I build on Azure DevOps was with version 2.1.300 of the SDK. After upgrading to .Net Core 2.2 with SDK 2.2.203 I get the error below.

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design/2.2.0/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(131,5):
>   error : rzc generate exited with code 1.

The container still builds successful on my local machine. I tried the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143235/getting-error-during-dotnet-build-in-vsts-ci-cd-error-rzc-generate-exited-with) post but with the same result. I even went back to version 2.1, but now with the same problem. Any idea what can cause this problem?

Update 09-05-2019
I've created a self hosted agent. It has te same problem, but when I build the docker image myself on the same machine (self hosted agent) the build is successful. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had multiple views within a components folder. This caused the problem for me. Hope it helps someone.